# How to get a value from running instance

Tags: java

Where i am maintaining one flag for running application
if true always my application will run continuously.

If flag is false have to stop running application.

Note: Parameters are considering as run time arguments.

How second process will change first process value.

Exe:

```
class Sample{


    public void run(boolean runstate)
    {
    
    while(runstate){
    //do something
    }
    
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: If `runstate` is never stored in a field the process never checks it otherwise it cannot be manipulated from the outside except when first passing it as a parameter (but passing `false` doesn't make much sense because you could just not call `run(false)` in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute "run()" in a separate thread from the main process. Use this code to break the loop:

```
class Sample{

    private boolean runstate;

    public void run(boolean runstate) // this runs in a separate thread...
    {
        this.runstate = runstate;
        
        while(runstate)
        {
            //do something
        }
    
    }
    
    public void setRunstate(boolean newrunstate)
    {
        this.runstate = newrunstate;
    }
    
}

class Other{

    void foo(Sample sample) // this runs in a separate thread...
    {
        sample.setRunstate(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: if running on different threads able to solve but if running on different instances facing issue to stop

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, there have to be 2 threads - one threads runs the above code, the other listens for a request to set the flag. Also, the flag has to be accessible to both objects running in the 2 threads.

Here is an example code that starts 2 threads. One keeps working till `FLAG` has `true`. The other thread sleeps for 200ms and then sets `FLAG` to `false`. The other threads detects this and stops.

```java
package practice.soflow.concurrent;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class FlagSetting{
    private static AtomicReference<Boolean> FLAG = new AtomicReference<Boolean>( Boolean.TRUE );

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        /* Main activity thread. This depends upon the status of FLAG. */
        new Thread( () -> {
            while( FLAG.get() ){
                //do something
                System.out.println( "Hi" );
            }
        } ).start();

        /* The controller thread. This changes the value of FLAG.
         * In this example, it will set it to false after 2 s; */
        new Thread( () -> {
            try{
                Thread.sleep( 200 );
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e ){}

            FLAG.set( Boolean.FALSE );
        } ).start();

    }
}
```

Comment: how if both running on different instances.

Comment: My mistake, you have mentioned "application" in your question. Well, in that case, the 1st thread remains the same. However, the 2nd thread and the 2nd application have to communicate. This can be done by various means: **(a)** opening a socket in the 2nd thread above, and the other application sending request to it, OR **(b)** the 2nd thread reads a file, which the other app updates, OR **(c)** same as (b), but through DB. However, you will need a set up on the first app of the kind I have mentioned above.